# VisualStudio Community 2013 prompts to update trial license

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I have installed VisualStudio 2013 Community, as per Microsoft documentation [VisualStudio 2013 Community](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2013-community-vs.aspx) is free and will not require any license.

But today I saw a notification on VisualStudio 2013 community IDE prompting me to update the trial license. Is this a bug?

Comment: An error message or screenshot would help.

Comment: @Patrick I tried adding screen shot, but stackoverflow slapped me saying I need to have atleast 10 reputations to post images. The error message is "Your license will expire in 4 days. Your trial will expire soon and you will no longer be able to acces the product"

Comment: have you had another VS editor before?

Comment: @Unlockedluca Yes I have got VisualStudio 2010 professional edition edition installed in the same machine.

Comment: @jaycyborg: If you give the link to imgur I will edit it in.,

Comment: I've gotten this same message.  it is exactly what @Unlockedluca says below.  While tool is free, it is effectively the same kind of free as the express editions used to be.  You have a 90-day trial license, then you need to sign into the Microsoft Community, at which time, the full free license will kick in.

Comment: I received the message this morning. I did have an Express version loaded prior to the installation of VS2013 Community edition, although I am not sure if that was what caused the prompt today of expiration. Anyway, a login with my account made the expiration warning go away, as others have mentioned.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Actually there is a dirty work around without signing-in , I used a free tool called **RunAsDate**  from this link  http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/run_as_date.html and set the date in the tool to the installation date. So the license never expires .

Comment: Nice crack! Isn't it kind of funny that we have to crack the "FREE" edition of a Microsoft product just to use it?

Comment: lol :)  yes . I still wonder why they call it community edition (free) when they impose restriction  to signin in to live account .

Comment: Sorry, for continue this topic, but where can i see the installation date lol, because when i run the program i was having wrongs.

Comment: No problem. The software doesnt show you installation date , it requires you to provide the date on which the software was installed. Either you should remember the installation date or you can use the file creation date as installation date from file properties of installed software. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Would this mess with, for example, `System.DateTime.Now` when debugging within VS?

Comment: I guess so yes , and in my case I was not doing any time related functions in my c# code and hence it was not a problem for me .

Comment: I tried it with VS2015 Community Edition and it crashes on start.

Comment: It works flawlessly until you need to use TFS as due to time change ssl certificates can not be verified .

Answer (score 26):

Have you signed in to Community?
Mean in your editor aswell on the homepage if necessary.

That should update the license and fix that. If you need to sign out after that you can. The license should be good for one year before you need to sign in again.

Otherwise it's a problem that you should address to the Microsoft VS Support not the SO Community

Comment: I have not signedin. this is a standalone machine which is not connected to Internet.Is there any other way to resolve this?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with the Microsoft Partner License, but it's my understanding that they require signing in periodically with your Microsoft Account credentials to activate your license, as Microsoft Partner License are not granted in perpetuity.

https://mspartner.microsoft.com/en/us/pages/membership/downloads/microsoft-partner-network-competency-roadmap.aspx

Sincerely,

Comment: So this means, VisualStudio Community 2013 cannot be used on a standalone machine even though it is free to use ?

Comment: As per definition of standalone you mean without internet than yes. But you could connect it shortly to the internet, login and that's it.

Comment: Yes, It is highly restricted machine behind firewall, Access to Internet is limited.Which does not permit to login to microsoft live services.

Comment: yep than you have your answer and can mark it as such.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Even after logging in to the Microsoft Account, it's still says "license expired".

Answer (score 2):

I had to install *VStudio 2013 **Community*** yesterday *2017 / 07 / 11* (*170711*), and I ran into the exact same issue.

Some context (I doubt that it makes any difference, but still):

- I have ***7*** other *VStudio* versions (paid / unpaid) installed
- Previously, I had a *VStudio 2013* paid edition (I don't remember whether it was *Enterprise* or *Professional*) whose trial expired (after 1 month; I didn't bother to extend it for 2 additional months), so I have uninstalled it

I've *Google*d and found smth similar on [[Unity.Forum]: Visual Studio Community 2015 - License has expired ?!](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/visual-studio-community-2015-license-has-expired.360642) (with a nice pic and stuff), which pointed out to: [[MS.DevBlogs]: Visual Studio 2015 FAQ - Community Edition is telling me my trial has expired. Do I have to pay for Community edition?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2015/08/07/visual-studio-2015-faq/#CommunityEditionTrialExpiry):

> No, Community edition is free to use. We use the same infrastructure that allows you to unlock VS w/ an online subscription to manage the requirement of signing into Community edition so some of our strings overlap cross these scenarios. **Trial here means the period you can use the community edition before you must sign in** to fully unlock the IDE.

So, after signing in (it's a simple email address/password sign in to [MS](https://login.live.com)), the *IDE* was unlocked. Staying signed in is not mandatory, I signed out, and the *IDE* still works.

---

#### Update

Today (*180821*), my *VStudio* license expired again for all 3 ***Community*** editions that I have installed.

Below, it's the ***VStudio 2015*** locked version:

[image: Img00]

After signing in (**[[MS.Docs]: Sign in to Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/signing-in-to-visual-studio)**), and optionally clicking "*Check for an updated license*", everything went back to normal. 
Posting some examples:

- ***VStudio 2017***:

  [image: Img01]

  Again, **no need to stay signed in** after performing the license upgrade.
- ***VStudio 2019***:

  [image: Img02]
- ***VStudio 2022*** (not yet necessary):

  [image: Img03]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I signed out of visual studio, and restarted my PC. That solved the issue. 
Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem today with Visual Studio Community 2019. The warning disappeared after logout and login again from my Visual Studio account and restart it.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately its not a bug but a feature. Its a lie from Microsoft that VSCE shall be free.

My story:
I had to learn it the hard way in my education in school when nearly everyone easily logged into his account: Because I did not ever programmed before, I was blocked since I had to first create a microsoft account and missed half of the class. Registering should be easy, shouldn't it? But if you have to get over 2FA, birthday, captcha, phone number, your first pets name, additional advertisings... - it sucks.

Here are some hard facts:

- Actually the community edition does not cost money but your data - Microsoft tracks your experience in VS and other connected apps. In the last decade we learned that sharing private information is indeed only another way of payment...
- In the past the last real free Visual Studio version was 2005 express (no trial limitation). Windows 10/11 complain about compatibility issues when installing VS 2005 on them, though there aren't any.
- 18 years later we finally got another free version: 2022 Community. It has a preregistered license.
- The algorithm to encrypt licenses in free and paid versions stored in HKCR\Licenses\ in a binary started 2010 and has not changed since 2015 (2013 is an exception).
- For educational reasons some people created "VSLicenseCpp" to reset the trial for 2015/2017/2019. I figured out, theoretically this would be possible for 2010 and 2012 too (not 2013 like it seems). I will not provide the link or usage here, since its against copyright. Anyway, with 2022 it seems there is no reason for using it at all.
- I heard, transferring the logged-in state (files in %appdata%) from one PC to another should work for some versions, but only for a while and at some point it breaks. Chance your account could get suspended, so I wouldn't recommend it too.
- Last version that offers Windows XP support was 2017: You have to use it with platform toolset "Visual Studio 2017 - Windows XP (v141_xp)".

Something likely but non-proofed:
I don't want to spread rumors about unverified things but I have the feeling, making 2022 free was not planned but an accident. The prompt says the license is applied, though nobody had entered a product key. Plus, if registry's encrypted binary gets damaged, 2022 community will tell you about invalid license too.
Thats why I can imagine when releasing the dev team from MS forgot to delete this key was used for debugging purposes. Obvious something like that would not be good publicity for the biggest software company so they let it happen as it was a present.