# Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition - "Your license has expired." even though it's a release (Update 4)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

This is weird. I installed Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition on two computers, with the same installer (and the installation started/finished around the same time) and there seems to be a problem with my licensing; one is activated and the other is... Locked, with no option to refresh or update.

---

After going through the installer and logging in, my first installation on my Windows 7 laptop went without any problem; it can run properly.

[image]

But when I finished installation on my Windows 8 laptop and logged in, I was presented with the following message:

> Your license has expired.
>   Reason: Pre-release software.

[Insert image of the error screen]

---

I've tried reinstalling, and there seems to be no difference.Neither does logging out and back in (or logging out, restarting the computer then log back in) do any help in refreshing the license.

As for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27939437/visualstudio-community-2013-prompts-to-update-trial-license), it isn't asking me to upgrade any trial licenses; just a "you can't use this anymore message" and no option to refresh or "upgrade".

**Note:** Please give me a hot moment to gather the screenshots from my computers.

Comment: Reason: Pre-release software.  Beta versions of Visual Studio are timed.  You need to download the release version.  If you are convinced that you already have it then feel free to panic about the health of your machine, registry and/or disk corruption is never a good problem to have.  One way to get in that pickle is previously having a beta version installed on that machine and it not getting properly uninstalled.  Tough problem to solve, try running setup.exe /uninstall /force.

Comment: @HansPassant The problem is that isn't the pre-release version though. Even though it's thinking it is. It's the release version with everything up to Update 4. *Otherwise, why would the first installation be valid?*

Comment: Read the rest of the comment.  And panic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue. The way I solved it was to go to Control panel and try to uninstall it. When the dialog box appeared I pressed the Update (or Fix) button. After that, I rebooted and logged in and it worked.

My VS2013 was a trial version though so my license was expired but I was not able to pass the screen of the screenshot you posted.

Hope it works!