# Visual Studio License expired after download

Tags: visual-studio

Today I have downloaded visual studio community 2017 for windows 7 64-bit But after download it said that its license has expired So I started searching and found that I needed to sign in when I signed in Visual studio said Your license has expired What is wrong

Comment: Sounds like a question for Microsoft

Answer (score 1):

I just got the same problem. In other answer suggest to sign in to your microsof accout to solve the problem:

[Visual Studio Community 2017 is a 30 day trial?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43390466/visual-studio-community-2017-is-a-30-day-trial)

But in my case I already was `sign in`. So I had to `sign out` and `sign in` again.

In spanish `Cerrar Sesion` is `sign out`

[image]