# SSIS Build and Deploy extension issue

Tags: visual-studio-2015, ssis, tfs-2015

I have been using https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TG.VSTS-SSIS Extension to build & deploy SSIS packages.

After I ran the build, I am seeing the following statement for the licence expiration as mentioned.

```
 2017-11-15T20:40:01.8111216Z Name    : devenv.com
 2017-11-15T20:40:02.6731416Z Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Version 14.0.25420.1.
 2017-11-15T20:40:02.6741298Z Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp. All rights reserved.
 2017-11-15T20:40:02.6741298Z The license for Visual Studio expires in 90 days.
```

Currently, I am having Visual Studio Client trail version. I just want to know am I really need to have licenced version of VS for these kind of build & deploy jobs using extension SSIS Build & Deploy?
Thanks,
SR

Comment: Can you build and deploy the SSIS packages successfully with the trail version of Visual Studio? Have you met any errors during the build and deploy except the licence expiration statement ?

Comment: Yes!Andy..I am able to build and deploy the SSIS packages successfully with the trail version.I didn't see any errors during the build and deploy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically the Visual Studio will be locked if the license expired completely, you can not use it any more unless unlock it (See [How to Unlock Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn950037.aspx)) . Not only the extension you used, all the functions related to Visual Studio will be not available that time.

However you can use the **[Community version of Visual Studio](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/)** if possible, it's free. You may also meet the expiration issue for the community version, just sign in and the trial info will go away. Refer to this thread : [Visual Studio Community 2017 is a 30 day trial?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43390466/visual-studio-community-2017-is-a-30-day-trial)

---

**UPDATE:**

Just as I said above, generally all the functions will be locked if the VS is expired. **So I suggest you'b better have licensed version or use the community version.** But if the BUILD & DEPOLY always works, of course you can still use the trial version till expired.

Comment: When I was seeing the following Build log file for the licence for Visual studio has expired.1. 2017-10-20T22:11:02.5436731Z Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Version 14.0.25420.1.
2. 2017-10-20T22:11:02.5436731Z Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp. All rights reserved.
3. 2017-10-20T22:11:02.5436731Z The license for Visual Studio has expired.

Comment: @Sat Do you mean that the VS expired but it still works? Are you sure it's the same Visual Studio Client? here you say " `2017-10-20T22:11:02.5436731Z The license for Visual Studio has expired.`" but in your original question it mentioned "`2017-11-15T20:40:02.6741298Z The license for Visual Studio expires in 90 days.`" . That means it has not expired yet. Or you have activated the VS again after the day  `2017-10-20`?

Comment: Andy, I am able to build and deploy even though the  VS is expired. Apart from that i don't see any other issue. When I have given the trail version of VS, I am seeing in the log that " your VS is expiring in XX days"..         I just want to check with you whether i need to have VS licensed version to do these kind of BUILD & DEPLOY Jobs?

Comment: @Sat If it works even though the VS is expired, then I want to say you are so lucky, I'm not sure why in your scenario, but just as I said generally all the functions will be locked if the VS is expired. **So I suggest you'b better have licensed version or use the community version.** But if the BUILD & DEPOLY always works, of course you can still use the trial version.