# Powershell date type unable to find

Tags: powershell, types

I am trying to use PowerShell to connect virustotal API, the code is from virustotal website and I got "Unable to find type [System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData]." error message.

The code as follow

```
function Get-VTApiKey {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param([String] $vtFileLocation = $(Join-Path $env:APPDATA 'virustotal.bin'))
    if (Test-Path $vtfileLocation) {
        $protected = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($vtfileLocation)
        $rawKey = [System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData]::Unprotect($protected, $null, [System.Security.Cryptography.DataProtectionScope]::CurrentUser)

        return [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetString($rawKey)
    } else {
        throw "Call Set-VTApiKey first!"
    }
}
```

after research I find I need to use add-type to add something to solve this. Any suggestion what I need to add?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure this is the code that's causing your error? You say the error was about `ProtectedData`, but the text `ProtectedData` doesn't appear anywhere in your code.

Comment: I believe that that is the type of $protected. Try adding Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Core  to your code

Comment: HI Joe sorry post the wrong code, updated the post

Answer (score 10):

[The MSDN documentation page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.protecteddata(v=vs.110).aspx) lists the assembly as `System.Security`. So you need to:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Security
```

You may also want to consider `System.Core` for some of the other Cryptography features ([google search lists them](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=system.core+cryptography))

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Core
```