# What will happen if I didn't sign in for vs community?

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I want to use visual studio for only visual basic projects. But what will happen if I didn't sign in visual studio community after 30 days trail?

Comment: [Is Visual Studio Community a 30 day trial?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43390466/is-visual-studio-community-a-30-day-trial) [Visual Studio 2019 Community says my 30 day evaluation period ended](https://superuser.com/q/1464628/272824).

Answer (score 0):

If 30 days trial license expired, you need sign up a MSDN account and login with your account, then click "check for an updated license" on account settings dialog, you can use VS Community permanent freely.

The easiest operation is that you subscribe to a FREE Subscription to MSDN（use a Microsoft account, such as outlook.com, hotmail.com, etc.） You can try to log in with your Microsoft account registered on StackOverflow.

[image]